# Ionic 2 Schedule a service

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an ionic 2 project where a customer checks remaining units through a service called by a custom provider . At the moment a customer can enter reference number and the provider will return the units as usual everything works fine . What i want is to call this service periodically in the background, lets say every 30 minutes and check the units so as when the units is below certain value i can notify the customer .

**GetUnitsProvider:**

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http } from '@angular/http';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
    import { Meter } from '../models/meters';

    @Injectable()
    export class GetUnitsProvider {
      constructor(public http: Http) {} 
        // get the customer units
        loadUnitsBalance(id:number): Observable<Meter[]> {
        return this.http.get(`http://example.com/balance.pl?referencenumber=${id}&api=json`)
          .map(res => <Meter[]>res.json());
        }
    }
```

**UnitsPage.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Meter } from '../../models/meters';
import { GetUnitsProvider } from '../../providers/get-units-provider';

@Component({
  selector: 'units-page',
  templateUrl: 'unitspage.html'
})
export class UnitsPage{
  reading: Meter[];
  clientReferenceNumber:any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public params:NavParams,private getUnitsProvider: GetUnitsProvider) {
    this.clientReferenceNumber = params.get("clientMeterNumber");
    getUnitsProvider.loadUnitsBalance(this.clientReferenceNumber).subscribe(reading => {
     console.log(reading);
     this.reading=reading; 
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your service:

```
constructor(public http: Http) {
  Observable.interval(30 * 60 * 1000)
            .switchMap(this.http.get(`...`))
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(res => this.check(res))
}

private check(res: <Meter[]>) {
  // check whether to notify the user
}
```

And then use this in your module (you would not need to inject the service anywhere):

```
providers: [
    {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        use: GetUnitsProvider,
        deps: [Http],
        multi: true
    }
],
```